# How does strength work in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, pullup

I want to create an assignment which takes care of pull-ups from a port pin. I wrote the following:

```
module test5;

reg value;
reg output_enable;
reg pullup_enable;

wire pullup_helper;
wire value_helper;
wire outp;


assign (highz0, pull1 ) pullup_helper = pullup_enable;
assign                   value_helper = output_enable ? value : 1'bz;
assign                           outp = value_helper  + pullup_helper;


always @(pullup_helper) $display ( "pullup_helper %b", pullup_helper );
always @(value_helper) $display ( "value_helper %b", value_helper );
always @(outp) $display ( "outp %b", outp );

initial begin
    $display ("Start");
    pullup_enable = 0;
    output_enable = 0;
    value = 0;
    #1
    $display ("1");
    output_enable = 1;
    #1
    $display ("2");
    value = 1;
    #1
    $display ("3");
    value = 0;
    #10
    $display("End");
end


endmodule
```

I got the output:

```
Start
pullup_helper z
value_helper z
1
value_helper 0
2
value_helper 1
3
value_helper 0
End
```

Q: Why does `outp` never change?

EDIT: Because the full answer is related to some comments on the given answers I will summarize the results:

As with support from Greg the answer to the problem is in two steps:

The default installation on Fedora 22 is Icarus 0.9.6. This version is buggy. As Greg tested also version 0.9.7 has the same bug. I installed the latest released version v10 (changed version conventions?)

The second part is simply let drive to assign statements into one wire.

```
assign (pull1,pull0)  bus = pullup_en ? 1'b1 : 1'bz;
assign                bus = output_en ? value : 1'bz;
```

With Icarus Verilog V10 it works as expected.

Comment: I expect by setting output_enable that outp becomes the state of  value but I always get 'x' as undefined. I can't get any kind of wire to work which can held the value of "low", "high" and "pullup" and no idea how to deal with that. I believe that my idea of a "wire" is totally wrong. It looks that it is simply impossible to drive a wire from multiple assignments. I simply can't catch the idea how the typical way in verilog is to deal with "wires". I think in the electronic way where multiple ports of a controller can added to a network. I simply have no idea how can I write that in verilog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verilog strengths can be a bit of complicated process understand. To get the full breath of understanding read: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 10.3, 21.2.1.5, and 28.10 through 28.16.

To print the strength of a bit in a display message, use `%v` instead of `%b`. (§ 21.2.1.5)

Verilog mostly works in the digital logic space. Verilog strength only comes into play when two or more assignments continuously drive the same net as a from of conflict resolution. The strength value does not propagate through assignment statements. The strength value can be passed through the verilog switch primitives: `nmos`, `pmos`, `tranif1`, `tranif0`, `cmos`, `tran`, plus resistive switch primitives (which weakens the strengths on pass-through). For verilog primitives switches refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 28.7 through 28.9.

```
assign (pull1,pull0)  bus = pullup_en ? 1'b1 : 1'bz;
assign                bus = output_en ? value : 1'bz;

assign                out = bus;
assign (weak1,weak0) outw = bus;
cmos inst_name (outs, bus, 1'b1, 1'b0);

// pullup_en output_en  |  out(%v)         outw(%v)        outs(%v)
// ---------------------+----------------------------------------------
//       0         0    |  1'bx(StX)       1'bx(WeX)       1'bz(HiZ)
//       0         1    |  value(St1,St0)  value(We1/We0)  value(St1/St0)
//       1         0    |  1'b1(St1)       1'b1(We1)       1'b1(Pu1)
//       1         1    |  value(St1,St0)  value(We1/We0)  value(St1/St0)
```

Pullup/pulldown logic from a standard cells libraries provide by your vendor  can be used for synthesis. Some synthesizers have pragmas to indicate a pullup/pulldown on a bus. Out side of that, verilog strength is typically not synthesizable. FPGAs have limited bidirectional bus support; if any. ASICs typically try to minimize the size and use of a bidirectional buses.

Comment: I still can't understand what is going on. If I simply `assign (pull0,pull1)  bus = pullup_en ? 1'b1 : 1'bz;`and let `pullup_en= 1;` the result is `bus 1 St1` displayed with (%b %v) . Why the strength results in strong and not in pull up?

Comment: What is the value of `output_en`? Working example on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/NTy)

Comment: Thanks for your example. The problem is the line 'pullup_en:1 output_en:1 value:0 ::  bus:x(StX) out:x(StX) outw:x(WeX) outs:x(StX)'. My expected result is simply that the output_en anables the driver and "overwrite" the pullup with 0 as in the real world. The result should be simply "0" and not "x".

Comment: I changed both assign lines in your code with the following ones: rnmos r3( bus, 1'b1, pullup_en );
nmos  p4( bus, value, output_en ); This seems to work.

Comment: Curious, what simulator are your running?

Comment: Icarus & vvp version 0.9.6; As I see that the version is very old ( it is the default for fedora 22! ) I compiled from scratch version 10. And what should I say: Now the code works as expected.... Quite hard to run as a beginner on such a bug... Thanks for your support!

Comment: It is a bug with Icarus 0.9.6 & 0.9.7 on edaplayground. It gives the correct results with Icarus 0.10.

Answer (score 2):

When I view the waveforms, I see `outp` is always unknown (`x`).  `outp` never changes because `pullup_helper` is always `z`.  `pullup_helper` is always `z` because `pullup_enable` is always 0.  You specified `highz0` for when `pullup_enable` is 0 in your `assign` statement.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 10.3.4 "Continuous assignment strengths".

Comment: My expectation was that setting output_enable result in value_helper becomes the value of value. And then I thought the strength of value_helper is higher and outp is set correct. But outp is never set. I still can not understand what the problem here is.